# jquery.countdown in rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am having some trouble with jquery.countdown (http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/)  when pushing it to my production env.

I have a init-script for the countdown that looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var clock = $('#clock');
    // init jquery.countdown
    clock.countdown(clock.data("time")).on('update.countdown', function(event) {
        var $this = $(this).html(event.strftime('<span>%M</span> min'));
    }); 
});
```

and my application.js looks like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery.countdown
//= require initCountdown
//= require_tree .
```

This works like intended on my local env but not on my site. The script is running but when I put a log inside of the countdown-function it doesn't show so it doesn't seem to be running it.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Binding events to `$(document).ready` doesn't always work as expected with Turbolinks.

Try this:

```
$(document).on('ready page:load', function() {
  ...
});
```

Turbolinks fires the `page:load` event whenever a new page is loaded (most links to GET requests, for example).